# Newly installed door frame a door. Since painting the door doesn't close. The door jamb is too close to the door on the hinge side

Tags: doors, door-frame, jamb

We've recently had some rooms reconfigured and all the door frames and doors replaced. The builders did the tricky work but we've been left to decorate. When the builders left the door frames and jamb were very rough. I've filled and sanded to make them look better,knot sealed, undercoated and top coated the frames and top coated the primed door. Since doing this the door won't close. There isn't enough room between the jamb and the door for paint. It's squeezing against the door jamb all down the hinge side. Having finished with the painting is there a way to move the jamb enough for the door to close properly?

Comment: Did you replace the doors with "prehung" doors, i.e., the new doors came with hinges mounted on the doors and hings attached to new jambs?  Or did the carpenters mount the hinges on the doors and hinges?

Comment: Are the hinges sunken down below the jamb or below the edges of the door? If so, you may be able to put shims between the hinges and the jamb. There are special shims made for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If wooden door frames, the jambs are usually just attached with small finishing nails.

They should be able to pull off easily starting at the bottom, and remounted leaving a tiny space between the closed door and jamb.

They might be stuck on the frame by the paint also, along with the nails.

Remove all of the jambs, top and sides.

Will probably want to sand lightly the frames and touch up or repaint before putting the jambs back on.

Comment: Thank you. Why didn't I notice this before. I've finished painting the frame. Is there another way without removing the jamb completely? I'm assuming I'll have the same problem with the other 4 doors upstairs which have also been replaced.

Comment: You could slice/cut/sand about a 1/16  inch at a time from the edge of the door jam.  Another way is to move the hinges out a bit, by filling the screw holes with toothpicks and glue.  Drill pilot holes in away from the first holes to move the door slightly away from the jam.